# Is there a way to add not minified config.json to Vite React project?

Tags: reactjs, vite

Adding a new un-minified config file on the Vite ReactJS app.

I am building a React-Js app with Vite.

I need to add a config.json file somewhere on the project.

That file must not be minified or uglified and must be changeable even after building the project.

I need this because my deployment team deploys the project with small config changes and they don't want to build the application for each time.

If I add this file under the public directory. My project shows it and works without minifying the file but the problem is if I change that file after the build it does not read from the application.